# Do datatables-1.9.4 support IE7?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Can anyone please tell me if datatables-1.9.4 support IE7?
My datatable is not working in IE7 while its working fine in IE8 and 9.
Please reply as I need this urgently.

Answer (score 1):

Simply I would say , 
**YES** 
But You will run from some issues as of slow working as well as some display issues